# Not all Javascript files are loading in Wordpress on server

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, p5.js

I have a WP custom template, my jquery files load perfectly but not my javascript files, I have tried everything to run them on my server, but they aren´t anywhere They are not in the code neither in the the net Tab, checked this out in all browsers, and it works perfectly in Local.

```js
wp_register_script( 'cltvo_functions_js', JSPATH.'functions.js', array('jquery', 'validate', 'swiper', 'scrollIt'), false, true );
 wp_localize_script( 'cltvo_functions_js', 'cltvo_js_vars', cltvo_js_vars() );

 wp_register_script( 'anm', JSPATH.'anm.js', array('jquery'), false, true ); //Everything allright with them
 wp_register_script( 'validate', JSPATH.'jquery.validate.js', array('jquery'), false, true ); //Everything allright with them
 wp_register_script( 'scrollIt', JSPATH.'scrollIt.js', array('jquery'), false, true ); //Everything allright with them
 wp_register_script( 'swiper', JSPATH.'swiper.jquery.min.js', array('jquery'), false, true ); //Everything allright with them

 wp_register_script( 'p5dom', JSPATH.'p5.dom.js', array(), NULL, false );//loaded on local but not in server
 wp_register_script( 'p5', JSPATH.'p5.js', array(), NULL, false );//loaded on local but not in server
 wp_register_script( 'p5sound', JSPATH.'p5.sound.js', array(), NULL, false );//loaded on local but not in server
 wp_register_script( 'sketch', JSPATH.'sketch.js', array(), NULL, true  );//loaded on local but not in server
 wp_localize_script( 'sketch', 'cltvo_js_vars', cltvo_js_vars() );//loaded on local but not in server
 
 
 wp_enqueue_script('p5');
 wp_enqueue_script('p5dom');
 wp_enqueue_script('p5sound');
 wp_enqueue_script('sketch');

 wp_enqueue_script('jquery');
 wp_enqueue_script('cltvo_functions_js');
```

This is what I see locally:
[local view in all browsers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NweUx.png)

This is what I see on my server:[server view in all browsers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YOFeO.png)

Comment: and what does your browser's error/network console say?

Comment: Nothing, not in my WP_DEBUG for php, neither in my console : /

Comment: This works fine on my server when its not inside WordPress: http://www.danielalmeida.mx/cantaro/
So I assume this might be a wp issue.

Comment: Why are `anm` or `validate` loaded everywhere when it's not even enqueued? Are you sure that is the responsible code and you don't have the script tags hardcoded somewhere in the theme?

Comment: How do you include this functions; which hook is in use to include this in WordPress? Do you load this in a plugin?

Comment: If this is a WordPress question then consider removing the [tag:p5.js] tag. More generally, consider posting a [mcve] that shows a **minimal** version of the problem instead. Try loading a basic JavaScript file instead of a bunch of P5.js files.